# error message on a line of code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am getting this error message:

> Warning 1 Variable declaration without an 'As' clause; type of Object assumed.

And here is the line of code that generate the error message:

```
Dim acceptedExtensions = New String() {".jpg", ".png", ".gif"}
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 6):

Specify the type of your variable as `String()`:

```
Dim acceptedExtensions As String() = New String() {".jpg", ".png", ".gif"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Option Infer`, and the compiler will infer the type as `String()`.

```
Option Infer On
...
Dim acceptedExtensions = New String() {".jpg", ".png", ".gif"}
```

The warning message indicates you have `Option Strict Off`. I definitely recommend **always** using `Option Strict On` to avoid all sorts of problems.